# Mac Contextual Menu for AFP Path Without Spaces

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

My team requires an Automator service that will allow us to copy file paths from within OS X Finder such that they always start with "afp://server-name/" instead of "/Volumes/server-name/" BUT ALSO replaces all spaces with "%20".

Right now, we are using the following code, which does replace the first space in a given string, but does not replace all spaces.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set output to {}
    repeat with f in input
    set end of output to replace(POSIX path of f, "/Volumes/Brand Design", "afp://nycp-afp01/Brand%20Design")
    end repeat
    set text item delimiters to linefeed
    set the clipboard to (output as text)
end run
on replace(input, search, replace)
    set text item delimiters to search
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to replace
    ti as text
end replace
```

Any help you can provide will be HUGELY appreciated; thanx!

A.

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of spaces use your replace handler again Inside itself (last line).

```
my replace(ti as text, " ","%20")
```